# Mounting device in fstab using labels

Tags: raid, unix, fstab

I'm trying to mount a device using a label in my fstab but it never actually mounts on boot.

```
#
LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc       proc    defaults        0   0
LABEL=RAID0        /ebs    auto    defaults,noatime,nobootwait        0       0
~
```

However, the following does work to mount the raid array:

```
mount LABEL=RAID0 /ebs
```

Any ideas why the fstab entry does not work properly?

Comment: Does 'mount /ebs', work? Have you tried removing "nobootwait"?

Comment: The nobootwait was what was causing issues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the "nobootwait" option. The device may not be ready when filesystems are being mounted, and this option causes the startup scripts to just ignore it and carry on.